# How to create agent with different criteria in Anylogic?

Tags: simulation, agent, anylogic

I would like to create a simple model.

Source -> Queue -> Delay -> Sink

Example; All Cake will have same method of process, baked in oven (model)
However, each cake, they will have own process time (delay), whether it is Cake A (Agent?) for 5min (criteria?)  or Cake B for 10min

How can I define that Cake A and Cake in source and set their respective process time (delay).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Many different ways, here is one:

1. Create an agent type "Cake"
2. Add a parameter "p_BakingDuration".
3. in your Source object properties under the tab "Agent", set "New agent" to "Cake" (now the source creates cakes)
4. You can load your cakes from a dbase table and assign the correct value for "p_BakingDruation" via the parameter mapping in the Source properties (create a dbase table with 2 columns "cake_name" and "bake-dur" and map the latter to your p_BakingDuration)
5. in your Delay object properties under "Delay time", write `agent.p_BakingDuration'. Make sure the units are correct.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for suggestion. I've tried and its working. However, I've multiple situation, First, from my last simulated result, I found the baking time is zig zag, means, after Cake A then Cake B then Cake A again. I would like to simulate, example; as the cake order (arrival) of Cake A is 2 cake/h and Cake 3 is 5 cake/h. My question is, how do I define the arrival according each Cake type. Thanks

Comment: This is a separate question, could you put that into a new question, pls?`(Helps future users to find it as well). thx

Comment: Hi Benjamin, kindly help me by check this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722620/how-to-create-an-agent-with-multiple-attributes-and-characteristic